# Do newspaper/magazines publish this type of ad?

Tags: realism, seven-psychopaths

In *Seven Psychopaths* (2012), a magazines (maybe a newspaper) publishes an audition for Seven Psychopaths in a classified section.

[image]

Do newspapers/magazines publish this type of ads in it?

Comment: Anyone else notice all the numbers start with "555-01"?  I know "555" is the universal movie prefix, but I wonder why they used "01" for every number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newspapers sell classified ad space for many varied reasons including Casting Calls etc.

They will have terms of service saying what should and shouldn't be included like these at the [***L.A. Times***](http://www.tronc.com/central-terms-of-service/)

As long as the advert isn't asking/selling anything illegal then they're free to print pretty much anything.

Take for example [**this one**](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3174043/Sean-Penn-puts-urgent-casting-call-pregnant-woman-birth-use-newborn-Cape-Town-set-movie-Face.html) by Sean Penn

[image]

Now, granted this was published in South Africa and not the US (where there are specific laws regarding child actors) but the point is clear.

**In the case of the linked image you provided, it's not even a casting call, it's a request for information...the psychopaths' stories for inclusion in a screenplay.**

It might be more common for this to be published in a "trade" paper / magazine but generally, sure, if the advertiser is willing to pay, the newspaper will print it....especially at a premium rate for color! :)